# HTTP Status 404 - /alfresco/testCMISfromJS.html

Tags: html, http, tomcat, http-status, alfresco

Estou a tentar correr um ficheiro HTML no Alfresco, que pus dentro da pasta (diretorioalfresco)/tomcat/webapps . De seguida, tentei correr http://localhost:8080/alfresco/testCMISfromJS.html mas obtenho o erro:

HTTP Status 404 - /alfresco/testCMISfromJS.html
type Status report

message /alfresco/testCMISfromJS.html

description The requested resource is not available.

O que se passa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já resolvi. Tinha os ficheiros html e javascript dentro da pasta errada... deveria ser (diretorioalfresco)/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/ .